# How to start and stop mule in maven

Tags: testing, maven, mule

I need to start Mule before I run my tests, and stop it when the tests are finished.  It is unclear to me how to alter my Maven pom to accomplish this.  So far I have the following in my pom:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-classpath</argument>
                    <classpath/>
                    <argument>org.mule.MuleServer</argument>
                    <argument>-config</argument>
                    <argument>my-config.xml</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

--- Update ---

After some replies below I decided to add some additional details.

I have several unit tests extending Mules FunctionalTestCase class:

```
public class SomeUnitTest extends FunctionalTestCase
```

I started writing some new customer acceptance tests using JBehave which are wired to run during mavens "integration-test" phase.  These tests cannot succeed without an instance of mule running.  The main class that loads and executes the stories already extends the JUnitStories class:

```
public class MyStories extends JUnitStories
```

Since I cannot inherit from FunctionalTestCase in this class, I need to look at alternatives to getting mule to run and stop when I need it for these stories.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use Mule's FunctionalTestCase instead? It fires up an in-memory Mule and loads up your configs. Not sure what you gain from starting the whole standalone Mule.

Comment: I'm using that now, but I have concerns.  First, it ties me to an pre-version of JUnit (v3 I think, and the current version is v4).  Second, I cannot confirm if mule starts and stops for each test class I extend with FunctionalTestCase, or if it stays in memory while the tests run.  If it starts and stops with each test case, then it may be less efficient than just running mule at the start of the tests.

Comment: First, it doesn't tie you to JUnit v3. Mule 3.2.0 brings JUnit v4.8.1 by default, but I'm sure you can use a more recent 4.x JAR if you needed. Second, you can control if you want to dispose Mule per test or keep it running for the all test case.

Comment: How do you control it so that it continues to run for all tests?

Comment: In your test case constructor, add: setDisposeContextPerClass(true);

Comment: Additionally, there are some deltas between what Mule exposes for tests and JUnit.  Please note a question I posted earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276197/can-we-use-junit-annotations-when-using-mules-org-mule-tck-functionaltestcase.

Comment: Reviewed my answer over there because the package from which you import FunctionalTestCase is actually meaningful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably accomplish what you want by leveraging maven's phases.  You'd have to define 2 executions.  One to start mule and one to stop it.  You'd start mule in one of the pre-test phases (maybe something like process-test-classes) and then stat mule after the test phase.  It could be pretty tricky, though.

Another possibility is to fire mule up in junit, somewhere like in a BeforeClass setup function.  This will probably be much easier.  See:
http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html

```
class muleDriver {
    @BeforeClass
    public static startMule() {
        ....programmatically initialize Mule....
        ....You should be able to grab the config files from the classpath....
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        ....Run Some Tests...
    }
}
```

The other question I'd ask is why you'd want to fire up the whole mule framework for tests.  I was on a team that did this, and tests ended up taking a tremendous amount of time during builds because they were firing up mule many times throughout the testing cycle (and other teams copied the pattern.)

Comment: Thanks Austen for the reply.  I don't want to "fire-up mule many times.  I'm trying to avoid that.  I want to start it, leave it running while the unit and acceptance tests run, and then shut it down.

Comment: Old thread - but isn't that the whole purpose of using FunctionalTestCase? Not sure if every test actually starts the Mule server for each test. If that is the case that may be a bit tedious. Experts kindly comment?

Answer (score 0):

Try using junit @ClassRule. The side effect is that individual test cases can not be executed any more.

```
    @RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({MuleFlowTest.class})
    public class MuleSuite {


    @ClassRule
    public static ExternalResource testRule = new ExternalResource() {

        @Override
        protected void before() throws Throwable {

            final String CLI_OPTIONS[] = {"-config", FlowTestUtil.getURI() };

            MuleServer server = new MuleServer(CLI_OPTIONS);
            server.start(false, true);
            mc = server.getMuleContext();
            muleServer = server;

        };

        @Override
        protected void after() {
            System.out.println("Shutdown");
            muleServer.shutdown();
            muleServer = null;
        }
    };

    private static MuleServer muleServer;
    public static MuleContext mc;

}

public class MuleFlowTest {

    @Test
    public void flowTest() {
        assertNotNull(MuleSuite.mc);
    }
}
```